# Error: before_script config should be an array of strings

Tags: gitlab, yaml, gitlab-ci

GitLab :

> .gitlab-ci.yml syntax error

```
docker exec -i XXX pip3 install -r ./requirements_os_specific.txt --target=./packages --platform=manylinux1_x86_64 --only-binary=:all:
```

this command giving a syntax error .

> "Error: before_script config should be an array of strings"

This work fine if I remove "`--only-binary=:all:`"

```
variables :    IMAGE_NAME: xxx   

before_script:
  - whoami
  - echo $GitLabPassword
  - docker login -u Prasenjit.Chowdhury -p $GitLabPassword xxxxxxx
  - docker -v
  - docker exec -i abc python -V
  - docker exec -i abc aws --version
  - docker exec -i abc pip3 install -r ./requirements_os_specific.txt --target=./packages --platform=manylinux1_x86_64 --only-binary=:all:
```

:

This script works fine if I remove the last line

Comment: can you please add your gitlab-ci.yml file in question?. Error clearly says error while specifying the command you mentioned in before_script section.

Comment: If I remove the last line from the before_script section then its work fine. Specifically if I remove --only-binary=:all: then its work fine.

Comment: doest that command work fines without GitLab-ci.yml?. I mean in local where you are running your container or throws an error. I am trying to understand if issue with the command you mentioned.

Comment: Yes it works fine If I directly run it from terminal.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

You have to escape a colon `:` in *yaml*. This can be done by surrounding the whole entry with quotes `"`.

**Replace:**

```
- docker exec -i abc pip3 install -r ./requirements_os_specific.txt --target=./packages --platform=manylinux1_x86_64 --only-binary=:all:
```

**with:**

```
- "docker exec -i abc pip3 install -r ./requirements_os_specific.txt --target=./packages --platform=manylinux1_x86_64 --only-binary=:all:"
```

Comment: awesome, I thought when writing commands/argument that needs the ":" is an [issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/issues/5609). You saved my life @sascha-frinken

Comment: One has to admit, that the error message is not particularly helpful in this case...